# Making an inline header style without span

Tags: html, css

I achieved an inline header (as I named it that) like the following:
[image: Inline Header style]
with HTML like below:

```
<h1 class="title-inline-left"><span>Inline Title</span></h1>
```

and with CSS (LESS) like below:

```
.title-inline-left{
    position: relative;

    &:after{
        display: block;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        background-color: #333;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    span{
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this **without** a `<span>`? (and better if with less code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using HTML data attributes, see the code below:

HTML

```
<div class="title" data-content="Inline Title"></div>
```

CSS

```
.title {
   height: 4px;
   background: #000;
   position: relative;
}

.title:after {
   content: attr(data-content);
   background: #fff;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   position: absolute;
   top: -8px;
   padding: 0 7px;
}
```

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eqyjfbj0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

***CSS***

```
.title-inline-left{
    position: relative;
}
   .title-inline-left:after{
        display: block;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        background-color: #333;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
   .title-inline-left:before {
  display: block;
  content: "Inline Title";
  width: 19%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<h1 class="title-inline-left"></h1>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4aa532vL/4/)

Comment: `content: "Inline Title";` need a dynamic solution. This is hard coded. :(

Comment: @MayeenulIslam try this out but here too you have to specify the width of the `.title-inline-left:before` http://jsfiddle.net/4aa532vL/16/